# How are images managed within an angular application?

Tags: angular, image

I'm looking for some very basic information about how an Angular application interacts with the server to get images.

I can put the images in the project assets folder, and then build the application. When I do that, do the images become part of the bundle that is downloaded to the browser on access to the application, or are the images retrieved from the server as they are needed? And if they are downloaded as needed, are they cached by the browser (so they do not need to be downloaded again)?

Finally, is there a practical limit on the total size of the assets folder (that is, before application performance takes a nosedive, either because of the initial load or because of the time spent downloading assets)?

Thanks in advance.

Nothing tried. Have no idea how to determine the answer to this question with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

When you do an `ng build`, Angular generates a `dist` folder for you. That `dist` folder contains the bundles AND an `assets` folder with your images.

To try it yourself:

- Add an image to your assets folder.
- Use `ng build`

Whether or not these are cached depends on the browser and settings.

To get optimized images, I'd suggest using Angular's `NgOptimizedImage` directive. You can find the documentation for it here: https://angular.io/guide/image-directive